# Master detail databinding from Dataset does not find the child table even when it exist

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core, dataset, relationship

This is my source xml,

```
<restcommands>
<command classname="org.openas2.cmd.processor.restapi" name="clearconsole" method="post" path="/v2/ClearConsole">
    <parameter name="OneDummy" type="string"/>
    <parameter name="TwoDummy" type="string"/>
</command>
<command classname="org.openas2.cmd.processor.restapi" name="writetoconsole" method="post" path="/v2/WriteToConsole">
    <parameter name="textToWrite" type="string"/>
</command>
<command classname="org.openas2.cmd.processor.restapi" name="listpartnership" method="get" path="/partnership/list">
    <parameter name="pathprefix" type="string"/>
</command>
```

and I am attempting to establish  master details relations with command and the parameter,with this code fragment

```
        DataSet restDs = new DataSet();
        restDs.ReadXml(new StringReader(restxml));
       // restDs.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        // Set up bindings for the master DataGridView (commands)
        masterBindingSource.DataSource = restDs;
        masterBindingSource.DataMember = "command";
        dgvRestCommands.DataSource = masterBindingSource;

        DataTable parameterTable = restDs.Tables["command"].ChildRelations[0].ChildTable;

        detailsBindingSource.DataSource = masterBindingSource;
        detailsBindingSource.DataMember = parameterTable.TableName;
        
        dgvRestCommandParameters.DataSource = masterBindingSource;
```

although the table parameter exists, it fails with the message **'DataMember property 'parameter' cannot be found on the DataSource.'**

```
detailsBindingSource.DataSource = masterBindingSource;
detailsBindingSource.DataMember = parameterTable.TableName;
```

Comment: ReadXml method has limitations.  On complex XML method will fragment the XML into multiple DataTables  where the data cannot be link properly.  You will need to create a custom reader is you want a  single datatable or use Xml Serialization.

Answer (score 1):

Try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        static string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
         static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            int maxParameters = doc.Root.Elements("command").Select(x => x.Elements("parameter").Count()).Max();

            //create data table
            DataTable restDs = new DataTable();
            restDs.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            restDs.Columns.Add("Method", typeof(string));
            restDs.Columns.Add("Path", typeof(string));
            for(int i = 0; i < maxParameters; i++)
            {
                restDs.Columns.Add("Param " + i, typeof(string));
            }

            foreach(XElement command in doc.Descendants("command"))
            {
                DataRow row = restDs.Rows.Add();
                row["Name"] = (string)command.Attribute("name");
                row["Method"] = (string)command.Attribute("method");
                row["Path"] = (string)command.Attribute("path");
                int count = 0;
                foreach (XElement parameter in command.Elements("parameter"))
                {
                    row["Param " + count] = (string)parameter.Attribute("name");
                    count++;
                }
            }


        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was working with XML data that contained a parent-child relationship between "command" and "parameter" elements. After reading the XML using ReadXml, the schema relation was automatically inferred and added to the Relations collection of the masterBindingSource. It was named "command_parameter".

Here's the revised code that works:

```
      DataSet restDs = new DataSet();
  restDs.ReadXml(new StringReader(restxml));

  masterBindingSource.DataSource = restDs;
  masterBindingSource.DataMember = "command";
  dgvRestCommands.DataSource = masterBindingSource;

  detailsBindingSource.DataSource = masterBindingSource;
  detailsBindingSource.DataMember = "command_parameter";
  dgvRestCommandParameters.DataSource = detailsBindingSource;
```